# "X-Requested-With" header is set, but not in php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, header

The X-Requested-With header is definitely sent:

```
myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider',
          function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

}]);
```

[Request Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAkR7.png)

but in php i can't get the value.

```
if($_SERVER['X-Requested-With'] != 'XMLHttpRequest') // <-- empty
{
  die('not allowed');
}
```

Comment: try [apache_request_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) or [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP header is expressed through `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` not `$_SERVER['X-Requested-With']`.

HTTP headers are prefixed with `HTTP_`, expressed in `ALL_CAPS` and have hyphens converted to underscores.